# Express.js how to use security on login and afterwards

Tags: node.js, security, postgresql, hash, express

I have a web app being built in express.js with a postgresql db.
I was wondering about how to implement the security, but everyone uses something different ( i guess thats a good thing? ).
Different modules different authentication sequences etc.
What I have at the moment:
1) User form post to for example /login
2) app routes to specific route
3) in route I try the following

```
var localconstring = "postgres://" + usr + ":" + pass + "@ip:port/db";
var client = new pg.Client(localconstring);
client.on('drain', client.end.bind(client)); 
client.connect(function (err, client, done) {
```

The database uses md5 so the pass is already protected by the db.

What should really happen?
Should I salt and hash the username and password and then save the salted/hashed credentials alongside the salt and then use the md5 of the db also?
If so which module?

Should I be logging in like that or try to do a select * from pg_roles/users ??

Thanks a lot! 
(regarding the salt and hash if possible some detailed examples as I am pretty knew with authentication security)

Forgot to mention. cookies..
After the authentication I set the following cookies:

```
res.cookie('user', req.body.lguser.username, { signed: true })
res.cookie('watcher', o, { signed: true })
```

And look em up afterwards

```
req.signedCookies.user !== undefined
```

Is the signed attribute secure?

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a key. This key should be saved on a cookie and on the database. Then when the user makes a petition, you can get the key on the cookie and search the user on the database.

There are libraries that help you on this, take a look at Passportjs:

http://passportjs.org/

Comment: sorry if I seem rude, but ur answer doesnt come close to the complexity of the question, its more of a straight out of the box answer. Why use server side hash and salt and not a pgcrypto module for the db and hash and salt them there? or even do both hashnsalt on the server then re-hash n store on a table using the pgcrypto module.

Answer (score 1):

First of all md5 is NOT seure anymore, so I would recommend you using 'sha512'.

A snippet would be something like this:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var salt = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(32);
crypto.pbkdf2(userPassword,salt,1024,32,function(err,finalPassword){
    //on the db you save the salt as a field and the SALTEDPASSWORD !!
    //in this case the finalPassword
}
```

So when the user logs-in you get the user from the db by username and do the following:

```
//after getting the user from DB recalculate the hash
crypto.pbkdf2(passw,user.salt,1024,32,function(err,corrPass){
  if(corrPass.toString() == user.password.toString()) // log in the user
  //where user.password is the result from the db query
}
```

And I do recommend using passport like the other dude said, it simplifies all of the cookie stuff.

Hope it helped !